# yaml file path configuration in launch file

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am newbie to ROS and want to know ,is it possible to update the launch file parameters in yaml file (through yaml-cpp parser) and configuring yaml path in launch file?

So basically i will have same parameters in both yaml file  and  launch file. in case if  I update the same parameters  in yaml file and configure the yaml  file path in other launch file then in this case launch will be also getting updated for those parameters updated in yaml file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267874/yaml-file-path-configuration-in-launch-file/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file, put

---

Originally posted by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0